# SARIMA vs SARMA model

Tags: time-series, arima

I've built two time series models using the same data.

One model is a SARIMA (1,1,1) (0,0,0,52) model built with at level data and the second model is a SARMA (1,0,1) (0,0,0,52) model built with first differenced data.

I expected that the results would be identical.  The results are comparable, but not identical, and are generally within about 1.5% of each other.

Does this sound like a plausible outcome, or should the results be identical?

My code and data can be found on my github repo here:

https://github.com/dkent603/General

Comment: Hm. [In principle, the two should be the same.](https://otexts.com/fpp2/non-seasonal-arima.html) It may be that there are some details about how the series are fitted in your software, so I would presume we can only help you if you can give more details, e.g., your data, what software you are using, and what specific commands you are using to fit the models. Incidentally, it looks like you are not using the seasonal part at all with (0,0,0,52) (which is more commonly notated as "(0,0,0)[52]"), correct?

Comment: I'm using Statsmodels.  You can see my code and data above. Correct - I am not using the seasonal part of this test.